# NodeJS Class functions disabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, object

I'm trying to create a class named `Debugger` with a public function in it named `log` but when I call `log()` from my other js file it doesn't work. I tried to log in console the object of the class and I can see in the console that my functions are disabled. Why? And how can I enable them?

```js
var Debugger = class Debugger {
  constructor(output) {
    this.output = output;
  }
  
  function log() {
    if(!this.output)
      console.log('WARNING: Couldn\'t debug to discord chat! Output is not set.');
    for(arg in arguments) {
      if(this.output) {
        if(typeof arguments[arg] == 'string')
          this.output.reply(arguments[arg]);
        else
          this.output.reply(JSON.stringify(arguments[arg]));
      }
      console.log(arguments[arg]);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Debugger;
```

```js
var Debugger = require('debug');
var debug = new Debugger();

debug.log('Client: ', client); // client is already defined and works perfectly
```

```
debug.log('Client: ', client);
        ^
TypeError: debug.log is not a function
    at DiscordieDispatcher.client.Dispatcher.on.e (A:\Discordie\main.js:29:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at DiscordieDispatcher.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at DiscordieDispatcher.emit (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\core\DiscordieDispatcher.js:37:16)
    at Discordie.handler (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\networking\messages\gateway\message_create.js:12:19)
    at Discordie.processMessage (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\core\MessageHandlerCache.js:11:55)
    at Discordie.processMessage (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\core\MessageHandlerCache.js:38:27)
    at MessageHandlerCache.processGatewayMessage (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\core\MessageHandlerCache.js:53:27)
    at DiscordieDispatcher.Dispatcher.on.e (A:\Discordie\node_modules\discordie\lib\index.js:82:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
Program exited with code 1
```

[image: The class which is not working]
[image: The error I get]

```js
// I tried this too and it doesn't work (same error)
function Debugger(output) {
  this.output = output;
  this.log = function() {
    if(!this.output)
      console.log('WARNING: Couldn\'t debug to discord chat! Output is not set.');
    for(arg in arguments) {
      if(this.output) {
        if(typeof arguments[arg] == 'string')
          this.output.reply(arguments[arg]);
        else
          this.output.reply(JSON.stringify(arguments[arg]));
      }
      console.log(arguments[arg]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Where is `debug` defined? That's your problem.

Comment: @tadman `debug` is defined in main.js

Comment: You can't have a function declaration within a class! I'm surprised there isn't a syntax error. You can only define methods inside classes as of ES2015

Comment: When I ask a question like that "where" means "what code created it" which means please edit your question and add the associated code to provide more context. Nobody is psychic, we need to know the details.

Comment: I take it you `require` or import debug.js somewhere in main.js that you haven't shown?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I did. sorry I forgot to put it in the snippet.

Comment: @AndrewLi How am I suppose to declare public functions of a class then?

Comment: @DrunkenPoney Get rid of the `function` keyword, try `log() {...}`

Comment: @AndrewLi I tried and doesn't work either

Comment: @DrunkenPoney Same error? I would've expected a SyntaxError.

Comment: @AndrewLi Exactly the same error (TypeError)

Comment: Are you sure that you include your `debug.js` file and not the module named [`debug`](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug). `require('debug')` would search for a module with the name `debug` in the `node_modules` directory and not for the file `debug.js`. If you want to include a `debug.js` in the same directory you have to write  `require('./debug')` or  `require('./debug.js')` instead.

Comment: changing your code to `require('./debug');` - removing `function` from `function log` **and** changing `for(arg in arguments)` to `for(let arg in arguments)` - and it all works ... trying to run your code before each of those 3 changes resulted in an error that clearly showed the problem ... 1: `Cannot find module 'debug'` ... 2: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` pointing to log after function ... 3: `ReferenceError: arg is not defined`

Comment: at a guess, your code is picking up some other module named `debug`, somewhere in `node_modules` (oops, like was suggested above :p )

Comment: @t.niese Oh god! I fill soo stupid! xD there is already a module called debug in node_modules